# vb.net winform picturebox in a tabcontrol getting error message when trying to load image

Tags: vb.net

As per the title, have a picturebox in a tabcontrol.
I can load an image in a PictureBox if it is not a member of the tabcontrol but as soon as I add it to the tabcontrol I get an error in the design window
BC30456: 'FromFile" is not a member of tabpage
code is:

```
Me.PictureBox1.Image = image.FromFile("c:\tmp\01_front.png")
```

What am I doing wrong?
This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Clarify *I have a picturebox in a tabcontrol*: did you add a PictureBox to a TabPage of a TabControl (e.g., `[TabControl].TabPages(0).Controls.Add([Some PictureBox])`)? If so, then what is `Me` in `Me.PictureBox1.Image`? It looks like you're referring to a Form.  -- You have `image.FromFile("c:\tmp\01_front.png")`, lower-case `i`: did you name something `image`? If so, don't assign names that conflicts with existing classes (as the `System.Drawing.Image` class). -- You are required to post code (in a clear context) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Stopped and did something else for 5 minutes and thought my way through the answer that I have been hamming at for 1hr.
Create the control and then add it to the tabcontrol. I was still thinking in the vb 6 way.

```
    Dim test = New PictureBox
    Dim tp = TabControl1.TabPages(3)
    test.Name = "picture"
    With test
        .Location = New Point(tp.Location)
        .Size = New Size(tp.Width, tp.Height)
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        .Image = Drawing.Image.FromFile("c:\tmp\01.png")
        .SendToBack()
    End With


    tp.Controls.Add(test)
```